# Auto-upload tool

Tags: vba, excel, network-file-transfer, internet-explorer

I created an automatic upload tool, which is working great (most of the time). As I want to improve the code I have several questions:

1. Is it possible to make the iexplorer process smoother? I don't like it that people can see the "sendkeys" actions. Is there possibly way to run the process in the background/lay a picture over the process? In addition to that, is there a way to block the user's input for some seconds? I know the opportunity of the `blockinput` command, but unfortunately it doesn't work.
2. Is it possible to close the browsers site (only the one, which was opened for the upload!) and return to Excel?

```
Sub speichern_unter()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim str_pfad As String
str_pfad = Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\" 'Die Datei wird auf den Desktop gespeichert
Rem MsgBox str_pfad
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs str_pfad & ActiveSheet.Range("m1").Value & ".xlsm" 'Diese Zelle gibt den Tabellennamen vor

'Zur Sicherheit wird eine zusätzliche Backup-Datei an eine E-Mail verschickt (optional)
MsgBox "Eine Backup-Datei wird erstellt und per Mail verschickt. Bitte bestätigen Sie im nachfolgenden Fenster mit 'erteilen'", , "OK"
ActiveWorkbook.SendMail "###@###.de", "###Dateiname###"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'Ab hier beginnt der Upload-Vorgang
MsgBox "Die Datei wird nun ins ### geladen. Dies kann einige Sekunden dauern! Bitte beachten Sie, dass Sie hierfür im ### eingeloggt sein müssen!", , "OK"
MsgBox "Berühren Sie während des Vorganges nicht die Maus oder Tastatur! (Dauer ca. 30 Sekunden)", , "OK"
Dim appIE As Object
Set appIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
'appIE.Visible = False
appIE.navigate "https://###/docs/DOC-257603/upload#" 'Link zur "Bearbeiten" Seite im TSN
While appIE.Busy
        DoEvents
Wend
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
SendKeys "+{TAB}", True
SendKeys "{ENTER}"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:04"))
SendKeys "{TAB}"
SendKeys "{TAB}"
SendKeys "{TAB}"
SendKeys "{TAB}"
SendKeys "{ENTER}"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
SendKeys "Desktop/"
SendKeys "{Enter}"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
SendKeys "{TAB}"
SendKeys "{TAB}"
SendKeys "{TAB}"
SendKeys "{TAB}"
SendKeys "{TAB}"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
SendKeys "###Dateiname###.xlsm"
SendKeys "{ENTER}"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:04"))
'Nachfolgender Ausdruck löscht den bisherigen Namen aus dem Textfeld
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
SendKeys "###Dateiname###", True 'Hier wird der spätere Name der Datei definiert
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
SendKeys "{ENTER}"

MsgBox "Die Datei wurde ergfolgreich hochgeladen", , "OK"

End Sub
```

Comment: Does the HTTPS server you're trying to reach allow you to use GET and POST? You could avoid using InternetExplorer *and* SendKeys, and use `WinHttpRequest` or `XMLHttpRequest` to send the data?

Answer (score 6):

There's a huge problem with using SendKeys to do *anything*. The very *second* the target UI changes *at all*, **your code is broken.** As was mentioned in the comments, the right way to do this is by POSTing to the URL.

1. Use a tool like [Telerik Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to sniff out the contents of the http request that occurs when you click the <kbd>Submit</kbd> button on the target page.
2. [Add a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3119794/3198973) to the [WinHttpRequest library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384106(v=vs.85).aspx).
3. [Use the library to POST to the target URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17570180/3198973).

   ```
   const url As String = "https://###/docs/DOC-257603/upload#"

   Dim httpRequest = New WinHttpRequest
   httpRequest.Open "POST", url, False
   httpRequest.SetRequestHeader "headerName", "and header values you sniffed out"
   httpRequest.Send "content based on request you spied on"
   ```